# Argument value loss using Listable C-Compiled Function

Tags: function-construction, parallelization, compile, variable-definitions

In my recent studies, I have come across a very strange anomaly with C compiled functions. When I call a function that has the 'Listable' attribute while global variables are accessed through MainEvaluate[...], certain arguments lose their value in the calculation and are treated as 0.

I have constructed a minimal (non) working example below where I declare a listable function with Compile.

```
func = Compile[{
    {arg1,_Integer}, {arg2,_Real,2}, {arg3,_Integer,1},
    {arg4,_Integer},{arg5,_Real,2},{arg6,_Integer,1},
    {arg7,_Real,3},{arg8,_Real},{arg9,_Real},{arg10,_Real},
    {arg11,_Real,2}, {arg12,_Real},{arg13,_Real},
    {arg15, True|False}},
    If[arg4 == 1,
        varG = True;
    ];
    {arg1,arg4,arg8,arg9,arg10,arg12,arg13}

    ,CompilationTarget->"C"
    ,RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True
];
varG = False;
```

Calling this function with the following arguments will return the following. (Note that arg4, arg5 and arg6 are given as a list of higher rank for the listable mapping)

```
func [
    1,{{1.,1.,1.}},{1},
    Range[2],
    Table[{{1.,1.,1.}},2],
    Table[{1},2],
    {{{1.,1.,1.}}},
    1.,1.,1.,
    {{1.,1.}},
    1.,1.,
    True
]
(*Return: {{1, 1, 1., 1., 2.04315*10^-316, 1., 1.},{1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}}*)
```

Does someone know why the 10th argument gets treated as aproximately 0 instead of 1? I have chosen this example to also showcase that this anomily does not happen if the computation does not call the MainEvaluate function.

I am using Mathematica 13.1 on Windows 10 and the C-compiler GCC 12.2.0 for compilation.

Comment: Numbers like `2.04315*10^-316` usually indicate lack of initialization. Writing random bits to a double-precision number field usually gives such crazy numbers. This is not the result of a calculation.

Comment: Here’s what I mean: https://binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050046048052051049053101045051049054 - notice that the exponent is all zeros and the mantissa has far too many leading zeros to be realistic.

Comment: Yes, I see that it isn't part of a calculation. The return value also changes every time I re-evaluate the second cell (calling the function), always returning a number in the order of ``10^-316``.
Is there a more proper way to initialize it?

Comment: You're expecting `arg4` to be an integer, but you're entering `Range[2]` into it (so, a list of integers). This could mess up the whole argument alignment.

Comment: I tried rearranging the order of the arguments, but that only resulted in another argument being wrong instead. However, no value was changed when the last 3 arguments were called as lists of a higher depth.
But shouldn't this be handled by the `listable`-attribute and is this actually a bug of this feature?

Comment: Your arguments do not correspond to the signature of the function. Check your arguments.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2863385).